# Remove key listener from panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

Is it possible to clear a listener that I put on my `JPanel`? When I call a method, I put a `KeyListener` on the panel but when I quit this method, I want to clear that listener.

Here is my method :

```
private void stopBall(final Graphics2D g2, int posBallY, String winner) {

        move = false;
        scorePanel.showPressSpace(true);    

        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){  
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ 

                    setPosX(getPlayPanelWidth()/2);
                    setPosY(0);

                    move = true;
                    scorePanel.showPressSpace(false);
                    initBall(g2);
                } 

            }});

        if (winner == "player1") {
            scoreCountPlayer1++;
            scorePanel.getLab_Player1().setText("" + scoreCountPlayer1);


        } else if (winner == "comp") {
            scoreCountComputer++;
            scorePanel.getLab_Computer().setText("" + scoreCountComputer);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: 1) *"Hey guyz.."*  For better help on international forums, spell words properly.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"when I quit this method.."*  'this method' being `stopBall()` or `keyPressed()`?  I find your question quite confusing.  Could you explain what you want to achieve in terms of what the user might see?

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` as this tests if the two String *objects* are one and the same (which you don't care about), not if the Strings hold the same characters in the same order (which you *do* care about). Instead use the String `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method.

Comment: Next, don't use KeyListeners with Swing applications, but rather use [Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Bindings are much more flexible and don't require focus to function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an unqualified call to addKeyListener(KeyListener), so I presume that you've extended JPanel.  If so, then you can call removeKeyListener(KeyListener).  In your current code, your key listener is anonymous.  You'll need to change it just a bit to hold on to that reference, like so:

```
// Create a variable holding the listener
KeyAdapter keyAdapter = new KeyAdapter()
{
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
      setPosX(getPlayPanelWidth() / 2);
      setPosY(0);

      move = true;
      scorePanel.showPressSpace(false);
      initBall(g2);
    }

  }
};
// Register the listener with this JPanel
addKeyListener(keyAdapter);

// Time passes...

// Remove the listener from this JPanel
removeKeyListener(keyAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the way with the absolute minimal adjustments to your code

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){  
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){ 
      ((JPanel)e.getSource()).removeKeyListener( this );
      setPosX(getPlayPanelWidth()/2);
      setPosY(0);

      move = true;
      scorePanel.showPressSpace(false);
      initBall(g2);
    } 
  }
});
```

But as already stated in the comments, you should opt for keybindings instead of keylisteners