# How to ask user to press any key to continue with conditions in java?

Tags: java

I have this code, what I want to do is only when the program is launched, the user should be able to press enter, and only once... until relaunch.

I have this label with text called `JLabel info = new JLabel("press enter to continue");`, when the user presses enter then the text of this will change and enter keypress enter should not function anymore, only when the program launches the user can press enter.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
      if(e.getKeyChar() == e.VK_ENTER)
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you just not remove the listener after Enter has been pressed?

Comment: How would I go about doing that, if the listener is not getting added to any frame or panel. for instance I could have said panel.remove(info), if I wanted to remove the label I added above.

Comment: Well, you are adding the listener to _something_ otherwise it wouldn't be listening would it. What are you adding it to?

Answer (score 0):

After the action (pressing Enter) happened you could remove the `KeyListener` from the Component. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046762/remove-key-listener-from-panel) for an example on how to remove the listener from a JPanel. I adjusted the code from the example a little bit:

```
KeyAdapter keyAdapter = new KeyAdapter() {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    if(e.getKeyChar() == e.VK_ENTER)
      ....
    }

  }
};

// Register the listener with this JPanel
addKeyListener(keyAdapter);

// Remove the listener from this JPanel
removeKeyListener(keyAdapter);
```

Comment: I do not want to add it to the JPanel, but to the whole window, would that be possible?

Comment: `addKeyListener` is working for `java.awt.Component`. Here is a link to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)